# Subset data.frame dynamically based on vector of column names and a vector of values

Tags: r

A simplified version of my set up is:

- 5 `data.frame`s in an unnamed list `data_list`.
- Each `data.frame` in `data_list` has roughly 20 columns. 10 columns are common across all 5, whereas the other columns are unique to each. The 10 common columns are all of type character, whereas the rest are typically numeric (but this is not guaranteed).
- A list of length 5, `column_list`, of character vectors. Each character vector contains a (potentially unique) subset of the 10 common columns of the `data.frame`s in `data_list`.
- A list of length 5, `value_list`, of character vectors. Each element of `value_list` is the same length as the corresponding element in `column_list`, and contains values that the corresponding columns (*in the corresponding `data.frame` in `data_list`*) may take.

The goal is to subset each `data.frame` in `data_list` using the two external lists. For example, if `column_list[[1]]` is `c("capital_city", "language")` and `value_list[[1]]` is `c("Sydney", "English")`, the logic desired is:

```
data_list[[1]] |>
    dplyr::filter(
      capital_city %in% "Sydney",
      language     %in% "English"
    )
```

And this continues for `data_list[[2]]`, with (potentially) different target columns (*as controlled by `column_list`*) and values for those columns to filter upon (*as controlled by `value_list`*).

The code above suggests a kind of `for`-loop. So far the best solution that I have found is to define a function like this:

```
components_filter <- function(df, x, y) {

  xl <- length(x)

  idx_logical <- rep(FALSE, nrow(df))

  for (i in seq_len(xl)) {
    idx_logical <- idx_logical + (df[[x[i]]] %in% y[[i]][[1]])
  }

  idx_logical <- idx_logical == length(x)

  df |>
    dplyr::filter(idx_logical)

}
```

and then use a functional programming approach with, e.g., `purrr`:

```
purrr::map2(
  data_list,
  seq_along(data_list),
  ~ components_filter(.x, column_list[[.y]], value_list[[.y]])
)
```

My question is whether there is a better, maybe more flexible solution to this 'dynamic' filtering problem. Thanks in advance.

---

Example data (for simplicity, instead of 5, these are length 2):

```
data_list <- 
  list(
    data.frame(x = letters[1:10], y = letters[2:11], z = 1:10),
    data.frame(x = letters[11:20], y = letters[12:21], v = 11:20)
  )

column_list <- 
  list(
    "x",
    c("x", "y")
  )

value_list <-
  list(
    "d",
    c("k", "l")
  )
```

these filtering conditions identify only one row in each case, so the desired output here is:

```
[[1]]
  x y z
1 d e 4

[[2]]
  x y  v
1 k l 11
```

Expanded example (e.g. `x %in% c("d", "e")`):

```
column_list <- 
  list(
    "x",
    c("x", "y")
  )

value_list <-
  list(
    list(c("d", "e")),
    list(c("a", "k", "l"), c("l", "m"))
  )
```

Desired output:

```
[[1]]
   x y  z
1  d e  4
2  e f  5

[[2]]
   x y  v
1  k l 11
2  l m 12
```

Comment: consider giving a small example of the datalist, columnlist and valuelist

Comment: `Map(\(dat,x,y)dat[colSums(t(dat[x]) == y) == length(y),], data_list, column_list, value_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative using tidyverse could be the following. Using `pmap` you can provide all three lists. For each list, convert the column and value lists into a named vector then data.frame. Then, you can join to your data list and keep rows that match.

```
library(tidyverse)

pmap(
  list(data_list, column_list, value_list),
  \(dat, col, val) {
    semi_join(dat, as.data.frame(t(set_names(val, col))))
  }
)
```

**Output**

```
[[1]]
  x y z
1 d e 4

[[2]]
  x y  v
1 k l 11
```

**Edit**: With the expanded example and nested list, something similar could be done. In this case, we would need first use `expand.grid` to associate different values for a given column, then a `cross_join` to create a reference data.frame containing different combinations between different columns. In the end, you will have a list a data frames than can be joined with `semi_join` to your data list.

```
pmap(
  list(data_list, column_list, value_list),
  \(dat, col, val) {
    semi_join(dat, 
              map(
                map2(col, val, expand.grid),
                ~ unstack(.x, Var2 ~ Var1)
              ) |>
                reduce(cross_join))
  }
)
```

**Output**

```
Joining with `by = join_by(x)`
Joining with `by = join_by(x, y)`
[[1]]
  x y z
1 d e 4
2 e f 5

[[2]]
  x y  v
1 k l 11
2 l m 12
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an attractive solution. A little cute my me, but would you mind looking at the expanded example that I've appended onto the bottom of the post? The idea is that `value_list` now is a list of lists (rather than a list of vectors) and it's not an equality that is needed but a 'match' condition (using `%in%` rather than `==`). Does using `semi_join()` like this lend itself to this extension easily? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your example above, you could simply use:

```
fn <- function(dat, x, y){
    dat[colSums(t(dat[x]) == y) == length(y),]
}

Map(fn, data_list, column_list, value_list)

[[1]]
  x y z
4 d e 4

[[2]]
  x y  v
1 k l 11
```